# Power BI How to find the end date of a month Q

Tags: powerbi, m

I have the start of every month in a table. What I am wanting to know is, how do you find the last day of the month if you have the starting month?

In other languages I would take the start date of a month, add a month and then subtract 1 day. How do you do this in Power BI?

In my example below, you will see the starting month in the Month field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EOMONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/eomonth-function-dax?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function to calculate that.

```
=EOMONTH([Month], 0)
```